# Authentication with passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, backend, passport-local

how to the redirect the user to [http://localhost:8080/${user.id}](http://localhost:8080/$%7Buser.id%7D) in passportjs . It must be done once the user is logged in. Can anyone help me ?.

Any example is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

> Remember to make user as a global variable (by using a middleware )which has id stored as _id

during authentication let say at login route

```
router.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect: '/${user._id}',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash:true
    })(req,res,next)
})
```

if you want an example visit
[passport example](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/)